# How to escape single quotes or otherwise reach the final result?

Tags: python

I have the following input:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I'd like to get the following output:

```
some blah blah ['a', 'b', 'c'] and blah.
```

I try the following but can't find a way to escape the single quotes:

```
f"some blah blah ['{', '.join(x)}'] and blah."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(f"some blah blah {x} and blah.") # will print "some blah blah ['a', 'b', 'c'] and blah."

print(f"some blah blah [{', '.join(x)}] and blah.") # will print "some blah blah [a, b, c] and blah."
```

Comment: Or even easier `print("some blah blah", x, "and blah.")`

Comment: Ok, this is great, it solves the OP, thanks a lot! but I am still curious how to escape the single quote in this case ....

Comment: @SkyWalker, what do you mean under "escape single quote"?

Comment: in the part `'', ''.join(x)` I would need additional two single quotes around the comma but would need to escape them ... how?

Comment: I gave two solutions can you explain what output you need? you probably just need to manipulate f-strings in the correct way @SkyWalker

Comment: @SkyWalker, you can use double quotes `print("some blah blah ['", "', '".join(x), "'] some blah blah", sep="")`

Comment: You say you would like to get the output `some blah blah ['a', 'b', 'c'] and blah.` is this a mistake? There are still single quotes.